# BeautifulSoup4 using conditional statements with tag object

Tags: python, if-statement, beautifulsoup

I wrote the following code to scrape info from the website for a bookshop and save this data to a JSON file. The code works fine, however I wanted to use conditional statements to filter the data returned with a specific word in the title (in this case 'Gardening'). No matter what way I try to implement this, it's returning all the books and not just the ones I specified.

```
bookArray =[]
content = BeautifulSoup(open("mywebpage...",encoding="utf8"), "html.parser")
    books = content.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "su-post"})
    # book is a bs4.element.Tag object

for book in books:
    titles = book.find('h2', attrs={"class": "su-post-title"})
    titleText= titles.find('a').contents[0]
    if 'Gardening' or 'gardening' in titleText:
            dateAdded = book.find('div', attrs={"class": "su-post-meta"}).text
            urls = titles.find('a').attrs['href'].split()
            year = getPublishDate(url)
            bookObject = {
            "title": titleText,
            "url": urls,
            "year": year, 
            "dateAdded": dateAdded.strip('\n\t').replace('Posted: ','')}
            bookArray.append(bookObject)

try:
    with open('bookList.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(bookArray, outfile)
    except:
        print("Write to file failed")
```

I also tried the following method but get the same output with all books written to the JSON

```
for book in books:
        if 'Gardening' or 'gardening' in book.text(): 
            #have also tried if 'Gardening' in book.string:
            
            dateAdded = book.find('div', attrs={"class": "su-post-meta"}).text
            ...same as above
```

Finally some sample output of the JSON file showing that the conditional statements are not having any effect

```
[{
    "title": "Of Mice and Men",
    "url": ["http://mysite...."],
    "year": "1937",
    "dateAdded": "2020-08-11"
},
{
    "title": "Wuthering Heights",
    "url": ["http://mysite...."],
    "year": "1847",
    "dateAdded": "2020-06-06"
},
```

*Further details:*
If I modify the code to print out every book, they are displayed in the following HTML format:

```
for book in books:
    print(book)
```

```
<div class="su-post" id="su-post-6238">
    <h2 class="su-post-title"><a href="ref to local file.../">Wuthering Heights</a></h2>
    <div class="su-post-meta">Posted: 2020-06-06</div>
    <div class="su-post-excerpt"></div>
</div>
<div class="su-post" id="su-post-8990">
    <h2 class="su-post-title"><a href="ref to another local file...">Of Mice and Men</a></h2>
    <div class="su-post-meta">Posted: 2020-08-11</div>
    <div class="su-post-excerpt"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide the url your use to get a better understanding what happens, please?

Comment: Hi, the webpage isn't publicly hosted which is why I'm using a HTML parser, but I can update the question to include the raw HTML for each of the 'book' objects in 'books'

Comment: Sounds good, lets give it a try.

Comment: Updated now, hopefully it make my question a bit clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem is:**

```
if 'Gardening' or 'gardening' in titleText:
```

Because "Gardening" is truthy it was always evaluating to true.

**Solution - Change to**

```
if "Gardening" in titleText or "gardening" in titleText:
```

**or**

```
if "gardening" in titleText.lower():
```

**or**

```
if any( x in titleText for x in ['Gardening', 'gardening']):
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks for the help!!! I really appreciate it, just once small change and it's working perfectly now :D I upvoted your answer but it says it's not visible since I have less than 15 reputation